# Declaration of a field - Import / Export CSV

Tags: python, odoo

My model: school.partner.school

Here is the declaration of my field:

```
foyer_id = fields.Many2one(string="Foyer", comodel_name="horanet.relation.foyer")
```

Here is my function to show you what I want to extract when exporting data:

```
@api.onchange('school_statut')
def _get_import_id_foyer(self):
    if self.school_statut:
        record_ids = self.env["ir.model.data"].search([('res_id', '=', self.partner_id.foyer_relation_ids.foyer_id.id), ('module', '=', 'horanet_tpa_smartbambi')])
        for rec in record_ids:
            print "Import ID Foyer de " + str(self._origin.partner_id.name) + " est : " + rec.name
```

My problem :

I wish that during my export, the foyer_id field exports the external identifier which is located on the name field of the table ir.model.data,

except that currently Odoo is exporting something like this: horanet_relation_foyer_5432.

Why ?

Example, for the partner_id (of the same model) which is declared like this:

```
partner_id = fields.Many2one(string="Child", comodel_name="res.partner")
```

I have no problem. It gets me the external ID and not res_partner_3501.

Why ?

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you muddle up `focus_id` and `foyer_id` in your question? Odoo always exports the correct external identifier. When there is none, Odoo will create one like `__export__.my_model_and_its_id`. In newer versions (i think Odoo 11+) Odoo also adds a system random hash at the end.

Comment: Yes, it's foyer_id. 
So it is impossible for me to retrieve the identifier in the ir.model.data model as the partner_id?

Comment: Why do you want another identifier than the right one? I don't understand your requirement.

Comment: Because I work on Odoo and another platform that has its own database. An export of this database was made in order to import it into the Odoo database. The relation that allows the export / import to go well is the external number of the partner_id (That's OK) and the external number of his foyer_id

Answer (score 0):

If you have not given a record an external id, one is generated for you by Odoo.

Go to Customers, remove the filter and find the `Administrator`. Export it (use any field). See that the external id now has `base.user_root` or something else depending on your version. That is because this is already defined on a `<record>` tag in it's `id="..."` attribute.

If you create a new customer and you export them, then you will see that a new export id is generated.

For version 10.0 this functionality is written here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/models.py#L734